# Sublime Text 3 - view freezes on startup

Tags: kubuntu, freeze, sublime-text

I recently upgraded from Kubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and now my Sublime Text 3 freezes when it starts up in fullscreen.
You cannot change the tabs, cannot start package control, cannot open settings, ... seems to be totally freezed.

The only thing that helps is to minimize and maximize it again...then it is fully usable.

Any suggestions what part of the GUI is broken?

Comment: If only ST3 freezes and no other programs freeze, I would say this is a bug with ST3.

Comment: See this thread on the Sublime Text [forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/3114-ubuntu-14-04-64bit-st3-doesnt-show-text-at-all/20173/8) and this [issue](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1219) on GitHub